# JavaScript for loop of an array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I don't understand why this piece of code doesn't work:

```js
let i = 0;
let arr = [];

while(i < 8){
  arr[i] = i;
  i++;
}

for(i = 0; arr[i]; i++) {
  console.log("Result:", arr[i]);
}
```

I want to log each element of the array while the condition is true

I know that **i** equals to **8** after the while loop, but even an "**i=0**" before the for doesn't solve the issue (BTW why the i = 0 inside the for initialisation doesn't set it to 0?)

Can someone explain me what breaks the code?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)` - this same pattern is also true for PHP as well.

Comment: The second expression in a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is the condition. `arr[i]` is probably not what you want since the first element `arr[0]` is `0` and therefore _falsy_ so your loop will never run. This is exactly the [same as in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: Or you could do `for(i = 0; !isNaN(arr[i]); i++) {...}` instead.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann   just why?

Comment: What a dumb error I did, thanks for your explainations guys!

Comment: @Phil: it looked to me that OP wanted to check whether the `arr[i]` was set.Checking for `isNaN()` is one possible way of doing that. Checking for `typeof are[i] !== "undefined"` would be another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops run until the condition is not true.

The first time around the loop `i` is `0` so `arr[i]` is `arr[0]` which you've populated with a `0`.

`0` is a false value, so the condition is false and the loop ends before the first iteration.

You probably want the condition to be `i < arr.length`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first look you set `arr[i] = i`. In the second loop your condition is `arr[i]`, and on the first iteration `i = 0`, which means `arr[i]` is 0 which evaluates to false causing your loop to exit.